# sscanf and scanset stops reading of hex numbers

Tags: c, scanf, uuid

I try to verify an UUID v4. I try to do this with sscanf, if the UUID can be read completly with sscanf (= total number of characters read - 36), i assume this is a correct UUID. My code up to now:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char uuid[ 37 ] = "da4dd6a0-5d4c-4dc6-a5e3-559a89aff639";
    int a = 0, b = 0, c = 0, d = 0, e = 0, g = 0;
    long long int f = 0;

    printf( "uuid >%s<, variables read: %d \n", uuid, sscanf( uuid, "%8x-%4x-4%3x-%1x%3x-%12llx%n", &a, &b, &c, &d, &e, &f, &g ) );
    printf( " a - %x, b - %x,  c - %x,  d - %x,  e - %x, f - %llx, total number of characters read - %d \n", a, b, c, d, e, f, g );

    return 0;
}
```

which return the following output

```
uuid >da4dd6a0-5d4c-4dc6-a5e3-559a89aff639<, variables read: 6 
 a - da4dd6a0, b - 5d4c,  c - dc6,  d - a,  e - 5e3, f - 559a89aff639, total number of characters read - 36
```

So far, everything okay.
Now I want to include, that the first character after the third hyphen needs to be one of [89ab]. So I changed `%1x%3x` to `%1x[89ab]%3x`. But now, the first character is read and the rest not anymore.
The output:

```
uuid >da4dd6a0-5d4c-4dc6-a5e3-559a89aff639<, variables read: 4 
a - da4dd6a0, b - 5d4c,  c - dc6,  d - a,  e - 0, f - 0, total number of characters read - 0
```

What am I missing? What is wrong with the syntax? Is possible to read it like this? I tried several combinations of the scanset and the specifier, but nothing works.

Comment: Sooo why not `d == 0xa || d == 0x9 || d == 0xb || f == 0x8`?

Comment: The character set format only reads strings. `%1x[89ab]%3x` This matches a 1-digit hex number, then a literal `[89ab]` string, then another 3-digit hex number.

Comment: Well, `scanf()` has only limited capabilities. You might like to learn about regular expressions, read the user's input via `fgets()` and check it by an reg-ex. Or, write your own checker...

Comment: "So I changed `%1x%3x` to `%1x[89ab]%3x`." Did something in the `scanf` documentation suggest that made sense?

Comment: @David Schwartz yea, as I read the documentation of scanf I saw no limitation to that. Now I see the remarks on the type further below in the documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `sscanf()` for this task, you might just write a simple dedicated function:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

int check_UUID(const char *s) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; s[i]; i++) {
        if (i == 8 || i == 13 || i == 18 || i == 23) {
            if (s[i] != '-')
                return 0;
        } else {
            if (!isxdigit((unsigned char)s[i])) {
                return 0;
        }
    }
    if (i != 36)
        return 0;

    // you can add further tests for specific characters:
    if (!strchr("89abAB", s[19]))
        return 0;

    return 1;
}
```

If you insist on using `sscanf()`, here is concise implementation:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int check_UUID(const char *s) {
    int n = 0;
    sscanf(s, "%*8[0-9a-fA-F]-%*4[0-9a-fA-F]-%*4[0-9a-fA-F]-%*4[0-9a-fA-F]-%*12[0-9a-fA-F]%n", &n);
    return n == 36 && s[n] == '\0';
}
```

If you want to refine the test for the first character after the third hyphen, add another character class:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int check_UUID(const char *s) {
    int n = 0;
    sscanf(s, "%*8[0-9a-fA-F]-%*4[0-9a-fA-F]-%*4[0-9a-fA-F]-%*1[89ab]%*3[0-9a-fA-F]-%*12[0-9a-fA-F]%n", &n);
    return n == 36 && s[n] == '\0';
}
```

Notes:

- The `*` after the `%` means *do not store the conversion, just skip the characters* and the `1` means consume at most `1` character.
- For the number of characters parsed by `sscanf` to reach 36, all hex digit sequences must have exactly the specified width.
- `%n` causes `scanf` to store the number of characters read so far into the `int` pointed to by the next argument.
- your conversion specification is useful to get the actual UUID numbers, but the `%x` format accepts leading white space, an optional sign and an optional `0x` or `0X` prefix, all of which are invalid inside a UUID.  You can first validate the UUID, then convert it to its individual parts if required.

Comment: I like this good usage of `"%n"` to simplify scanning success.

Answer (score 2):

> Now I want to include, that the first character after the third hyphen needs to be one of `[89ab]`. So I changed `%1x%3x` to `%1x[89ab]%3x`

Should have been `"%1[89ab]%3x"` and then saved into a 2 character string.  Then convert that small string into a hex value with `strtol(..., ..., 16)`.

---

Instead, I suggest a 2 step validation for [universally unique identifier (UUID)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier)
:
Check for syntax, then read the value.

I'd avoid `"%x"` as it allows leading spaces, leading `'+','-'` and optional leading `0x` and narrow inputs.

For validation, perhaps a simply test in code:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>

// byte lengths: 4-2-2-2-6
typedef struct {
  unsigned long time_low;
  unsigned time_mid;
  unsigned time_hi_and_version;
  unsigned clock_seq_hi_and_res_clock_seq_low;
  unsigned long long node;
} uuid_T;

uuid_T* validate_uuid(uuid_T *dest, const char *uuid_source) {
  static const char *uuid_pat = "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx";
  const char *pat = uuid_pat;
  const unsigned char *u = (const unsigned char*) uuid_source;

  while (*u) {
    if ((*pat++ == 'x' && !isxdigit(*u)) || *u != '-') {
      return NULL;
    }
    u++;
  }
  if (*pat) {  // Too short
    return NULL;
  }
  sscanf(uuid_source, "%lx-%x-%x-%x-%llx", &dest->time_low,
      &dest->time_mid, &dest->time_hi_and_version,
      &dest->clock_seq_hi_and_res_clock_seq_low, &dest->node);
  return dest;
}
```

`u` is `unsigned char *u` so `isxdigit(*u)` is only called with non-negative values and so avoids UB,

Comment: *optional leading `0x`*: nice catch!